# Laravel Auth reset password with custom messages

Tags: laravel

I'm using the Laravel Auth but I would like to have custom error messages for the passwor reset.

With the defautl configurations the messages are like:

- if the user dont fill the email field it appears "validation.required" or "The email field is required." with "en" language in app.php.
- if the user fill the email with an email that dont exist in the users table it appears "passwords.user" or "We can't find a user with that e-mail address." with "en" language in app.php.
- if the user fill the email with an email with invalid format it appears "validation.email" or "The email must be a valid email address." with "en" language in app.php.

But I want to have custom messages like:

```
$rules = [
    'email' => 'required|email|exists:users.email'
];

$messages = [
    'email.required' => 'The email is required.',
    'email.email' => 'The email needs to have a valid format.',
    'email.exists' => 'The email is not registered in the system.',
];


$this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);
```

Do you know how to have custom messages for the reset password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ResetPasswordController use `ResetsPasswords` trait and it has 2 methods (`rules` and `validationErrorMessages`) that deal with validation rule and its message. If you want to change validation and its message then overwrite both function in `ResetPasswordController`.

Define your rules in it

```
protected function rules()
{
    return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ];
}
```

Define your custom message

```
protected function validationErrorMessages()
{
   return [];
}
```

Details you can check here https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.html

Comment: I just want to confirm that I tried this and it works with Laravel 7.x as well even though there were many changes in Laravel 7.x with user authentication moving to Laravel UI.